# Get list of #defines as Token or string in Premake 5

Tags: lua, nasm, premake

I am using a custom build command to run the nasm assembler on a `.asm` file in my C++ project. I am using `%idef`s in the assembler code to only compile the code I need. I am checking for the same `#define`s as in the C++-Code and use `define()` in Premake 5 to set those, but additionally I need to pass them to nasm on its command line invocation in my Custom Build Command. What I am looking for is a way to concatenate or string replace the Premake internal list of `#define`s into the command line invocation string of the `buildcommands()` call. Is there a Premake [Token](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Tokens) or a way to introspect the lua variables and generate a list from that?

Note that my command line invocation specifically is

```lua
buildcommands "nasm.exe -f win32 -o %{cfg.objdir}%{file.basename}.lib %{file.abspath} -DNDEBUG"
```

Suppose I set `defines { "FEAT_A", "FEAT_B" }` in my `premake5.lua`. I then would like to to add `-DFEAT_A -DFEAT_B` automatically to that build command similar to the `-DNDEBUG` so I cannot simply insert a simple token. I guess I do have to do something like this (lua pseudo code as I don't really know the syntax):

```lua
define_flags = wks.defines.join(" -D")
buildcoommands("nasm.exe [...]"..define_flags)
```

Do you know if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
buildcommands('nasm.exe [...] %{table.implode(cfg.defines, "-D", "", " ")} [...]')
```